# PayPal Adaptive Payments PHP API - The receiver does not accept payments in this Currency

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using Adaptive Payments API to make a chained payment in USD but i'm getting the error `The receiver does not accept payments in this Currency` - i've checked both receiving accounts and the settings for block payments is set to `No, accept them and convert them to British Pounds`. Strange thing is when I do the same transaction as a parallel payment with the same two receiving accounts, it works fine and payment can be made, only when I set one account as the primary receiver, then I get this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a question for paypal to answer?

Comment: @wasim  did you find out why the error happens? I have the same issue. I changed the currency settings for the test accounts in the sandbox to accept/convert currencies.

Comment: No I never figured it out, stopped working on it.